# Functions with flexible arguments in python

Tags: python

I am novice in python. I was writing a function with flexible arguments. But it is giving only result of first argument. I need results for every argument. Please tell me how to tackle this.

```
def many_squares(*args):
    for ar in args:
        squares=ar**2
        return(squares)
many_squares(25,28,35)
625
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue isn't with `*args`, it's with `return`. Once the interpreter hits `return` the function exits, so you never get beyond the first iteration in the loop. You probably want to make a list of the results and return that list:

```py
def many_squares(*args):
    out = []
    for ar in args:
        out.append(ar**2)
    return out

many_squares(25,28,35)
[625, 784, 1225]
```

For this particular code, it's much simpler to do it all as a list comprehension.

```py
def many_squares(*args):
    return [ar**2 for ar in args]
```

You might also be interested in using `yield` instead of `return`; see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/231767/what-does-the-yield-keyword-do) for explanation.

Answer (score 2):

Try using a `sum_`:

```
def many_squares(*args):
    sum_ = 0

    for ar in args:
        sum_+=ar**2

    return sum_

many_squares(25,28,35)
```

EDIT: If you need every value recorded into a list, try:

```
def many_squares(*args):
    list_ = []

    for ar in args:
        list_.append(ar**2)

    return list_

many_squares(25,28,35)
```

or use list comprehension as people said.

Answer (score 1):

**List Comprehensions** to the rescue

```py
def many_squares(*args):
    return [a**2 for a in args]
```

Alternatively, you can use a for loop

```py
def many_squares(*args):
    res = [0,]*len(args)
    for idx, a in enumerate(args):
        res[idx] = a**2
    return res
```